# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match the referencing column list in the foreign key1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know this question has been asked several time before and I've read all the responses and still can't figure it out.  I have these tables, when I try to create them I get the error above. When I eliminate one of the key in the Userinfo table the code works fine but when I make it a composite key it doesn't.  I hope someone can help me, I am new to SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo]
(
    [UserId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [strEmail] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [strLastName] varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
    [strFirstName] varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
    [strMiddleInitial] varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
    [strDSNPhone] varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
    [dCreationDate] date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-1-1',
    [dDD2875Approved] date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-1-1', 
    [dDD2875Expires] date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-1-1',
 )

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files]
 (
     [FileID] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
     [strFileName] varchar(200) NULL,
     [strFilePath] varchar(400) NULL,
     [strFileDescription] varchar(200) NULL,
     [UserId] int NOT NULL,
     [strEmail] varchar(100) NOT NULL
 )

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Files] 
 ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Files]
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([FileID] ASC)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_UserInfo]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [strEmail] ASC)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Files] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Files_UserInfo]
    FOREIGN KEY ([UserId],[strEmail]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserInfo]([strEmail],[UserId]) 
         ON DELETE No Action ON UPDATE No Action
```

Comment: Column order matters. For some reason you're reversing the columns in the second part of the FK reference and so of course there's a data type mismatch there.

Comment: That worked.  Changing the order in the FK. I am using Enterprise Architect to generate the sql code and for some reason it revered the columns.  Thanks. Please put your comment in an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure should be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo] (
    [UserId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [strEmail] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [strLastName] varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
    [strFirstName] varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
    [strMiddleInitial] varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
    [strDSNPhone] varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
    [dCreationDate] date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01',
    [dDD2875Approved] date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01', 
    [dDD2875Expires] date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01',
 );

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files] (
     [FileID] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
     [strFileName] varchar(200) NULL,
     [strFilePath] varchar(400) NULL,
     [strFileDescription] varchar(200) NULL,
     [UserId] int NOT NULL REFERENCES user_info(UserId),
     [strEmail] varchar(100) NOT NULL    
 );
```

Notes:

- You can add the primary and foreign key definitions in the table.
- When you have an `identity` column, there is no need for a composite primary key.
- Only the identity column should be used for the foreign key reference.
- You probably don't want to repeat information such as `strEmail` in the files table.  You can look it up using `JOIN`.
- I'm not sure what your aversion to `NULL`s is in the `UserInfo` table, but presumably you have a good reason for using such defaults.

Comment: I am transfering data from an old database that has null's in it that I can't have in the new db. So I need a default values.

Answer (score 0):

`[UserId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)` is unique.
Adding `[strEmail] ASC` to the primary key adds no value.

Adding `[strEmail]` to the foreign key adds no value.

`[strEmail]` should not be in the `Files` table.